# Can't debug remote docker on some machines from Visual Studio: VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher only supports remote Unix machines

Tags: docker, visual-studio, debugging

I have a .NET 7 application running in a Linux docker container, on an Ubuntu machine. I'm unable to attach Visual Studio (on Windows 11) to my application. I can connect to other .NET applications inside Docker on other Ubuntu machines.

I get this error:
Failed to launch debug adapter 'coreclr'.
VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher only supports remote Unix machines!

The Attach-to-process wizard can see the containers and can see the processes inside those containers, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the ssh connection.

I haven't found anything online on this error.

Extra info: Output of Debug Adapter Host Log, after running this command: `DebugAdapterHost.Logging /On /OutputWindow`

```
 1> DebugAdapterHost version: 17.6.10530.1 commit:a8b80a80533cc2b91039497e292d6997b60501a6
 1> ERROR: Failed to launch debug adapter!

DebugAdapterLaunchException: Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

Failure Location: LaunchingProcess
Inner Exception: 
    InvalidOperationException: VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher only supports remote Unix machines!

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VsDbg.Integration.AdapterLauncher.VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DebugAdapterHost.Interfaces.IAdapterLauncher.LaunchAdapter(IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.AdapterHosting.DebugAdapterProcessConnection..ctor(ConfigurationWrapper configuration, IDiagnosticLogger log, IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop, IAdapterLauncher launcher)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.AdapterHosting.DebugAdapterHostFactory.CreateDebugAdapterHost(ConfigurationWrapper configuration, IDiagnosticLogger log, ExtensibilityManager extensibilityManager, IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop, Boolean registerStandardHandlers, DebugProtocolOptions options, Action`1 syncRequestErrorHandler)

 1> ERROR: Unexpected error

DebugAdapterLaunchException: Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.AdapterHosting.DebugAdapterHostFactory.CreateDebugAdapterHost(ConfigurationWrapper configuration, IDiagnosticLogger log, ExtensibilityManager extensibilityManager, IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop, Boolean registerStandardHandlers, DebugProtocolOptions options, Action`1 syncRequestErrorHandler)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.AdapterHosting.DebugAdapterHostFactory.CreateDebugAdapterHost(DebuggedProcess process, IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.Engine.Implementation.DebuggedProcess.StartDebugAdapter(IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop)

Failure Location: LaunchingProcess
Inner Exception: 
    InvalidOperationException: VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher only supports remote Unix machines!

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VsDbg.Integration.AdapterLauncher.VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DebugAdapterHost.Interfaces.IAdapterLauncher.LaunchAdapter(IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.AdapterHosting.DebugAdapterProcessConnection..ctor(ConfigurationWrapper configuration, IDiagnosticLogger log, IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop, IAdapterLauncher launcher)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.AdapterHosting.DebugAdapterHostFactory.CreateDebugAdapterHost(ConfigurationWrapper configuration, IDiagnosticLogger log, ExtensibilityManager extensibilityManager, IAdapterLaunchInfo launchInfo, ITargetHostInterop targetInterop, Boolean registerStandardHandlers, DebugProtocolOptions options, Action`1 syncRequestErrorHandler)

 1> ERROR: Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

VsDbgRemoteUnixLauncher only supports remote Unix machines!
```

Comment: What is your base image?
What is the result of running `uname` in the container?

Comment: The base image is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine. The result of uname inside the container is: Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working! I troubleshooted the issue by using auditd to log the commands Visual Studio was executing on the docker host. By executing these commands manually, I had a lot more info on what went wrong.

In my case, this command failed:

```
docker exec -i myapp /bin/sh -c 'echo shell-process:$$ >> /proc/[0-9]*/cmdline; for filename in /proc/[0-9]*/cmdline 2>/dev/null; do echo -e "\nfilename:$filename\n" && cat $filename; done'
```

It failed because the directory .docker in the home-directory of the SSH user used to remote debug, was owned by root. Changing the owner to the correct user fixed my issue.

For anyone reading this having a similar, but not the same issue:
**[Edit: I found a much easier way to debug, skip to the bottom!]**

Install and start auditd, add these rules at the end of /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S execve -k auditcmd
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -k auditcmd
```

Then run these commands:

```
augenrules 
service auditd stop
service auditd start
```

Try attaching in VS, then execute:

```
ausearch -ua userYouUseForSshConnection
```

This will display all commands executed by that user. Probably the last one will indicate the problem.

**Edit**

I found a much easier way to debug what's going wrong. Just open a fresh ssh session (with the same user as you use in VS) to the Docker host right after trying to remote debug. Use the up arrow to see the last command(s) VS executed.

Comment: Good catch, well done. I have edited my answer with some additional comments.

Answer (score 1):

Given the base image is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine` and the result of `uname` inside the container is `Linux`, that means the container itself should be a compatible Unix environment for [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2022) with Visual Studio.

As a workaround, you can try running the application outside of Docker to isolate whether the issue is Docker-specific or related to the application's configuration.

I can find only this [other case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-remote-debugging-over-SSH-does-no/10394545), which points out to:

- "[Debug .NET Core on Linux using SSH by attaching to a process Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022)": make sure those have been followed
- some logs: "Can you grab additional logs by going to the Command Window (`View -> Other Windows -> Command Window`) and enter `DebugAdapterHost.Logging /On /OutputWindow`. This will drop additional logs in the Output pane if you switch to `Show output from: Debug Adapter Host Log`."

---

In the context of Docker and remote debugging, a firewall could also potentially be an issue. Even if the application is running inside a Docker container on an Alpine Linux base image, network communication between your Windows 11 machine running Visual Studio and the Docker container on the remote Ubuntu machine would go through the network stack of the host machine, which is subject to the host's firewall settings.

```bash
┌──────────────────┐     SSH (TCP/22)    ┌──────────────────┐ Docker Port Mapping  ┌──────────────────┐
│ Windows 11       │────────────────────►│ Ubuntu Machine   │◄────────────────────►│ Docker Container │
│ Machine          │                     │                  │                      │                  │
│ ┌──────────────┐ │                     │ ┌──────────────┐ │                      │ ┌──────────────┐ │
│ │ Visual       │ │                     │ │ SSH Daemon   │ │                      │ │ .NET App     │ │
│ │ Studio       │ │                     │ │ (sshd)       │ │                      │ │              │ │
│ └──────────────┘ │                     │ └──────────────┘ │                      │ └──────────────┘ │
│                  │                     │                  │                      │ │ VsDbg        │ │
│                  │                     │                  │                      │ └──────────────┘ │
└──────────────────┘                     └──────────────────┘                      └──────────────────┘
```

When debugging a .NET application remotely with Visual Studio, several ports could be involved, depending on the configuration and the services used. Make sure port 22 (or your configured SSH port) is open for incoming connections on the Ubuntu machine.

```bash
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

Find out which port VsDbg is using and make sure it is open. If it is dynamic, you might need to set up a specific port and expose it when starting the Docker container.

```bash
docker run -d -p <host-port>:<container-debug-port> myapp:tag
sudo ufw allow <host-port>/tcp
```

Make sure your Docker run command exposes the necessary ports, e.g., `-p 8080:80` would expose port 80 from the container to port 8080 on the host.

---

The [OP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77475067/6309a) uses `auditd` to log the commands executed by Visual Studio on the Docker host.
You can see it illustrated in this 2018 article "[Auditing Docker Containers in a DevOps Environment](https://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2018/43/Auditing-Docker-Containers-in-a-DevOps-Environment)" by [Chris Binnie](https://github.com/chrisbinnie).

```bash
┌──────────────────┐     SSH (TCP/22)    ┌──────────────────┐  
│ Windows 11       │────────────────────►│ Ubuntu Machine   │
│ Machine          │                     │                  │                      
│ ┌──────────────┐ │                     │ ┌──────────────┐ │                      
│ │ Visual       │ │                     │ │ SSH Daemon   │ │                      
│ │ Studio       │ │                     │ │ (sshd)       │ │                      
│ └──────────────┘ │                     │ └──────────────┘ │                      
│                  │                     │                  │                      
│                  │                     │ ┌──────────────┐ │                      
└──────────────────┘                     │ │ .docker dir  │ │                      
                                         │ │ (Ownership)  │ │                      
                                         │ └──────────────┘ │                      
                                         └──────────────────┘                      
  ┌──────────────────┐      Docker Port Mapping    |                     
  │ Docker Container │◄────────────────────────────┘                                                    
  │                  │                                                  
  │ ┌──────────────┐ │                                              
  │ │ .NET App     │ │                                                  
  │ │              │ │                                                  
  │ └──────────────┘ │                                                  
  │ │ VsDbg        │ │                                                  
  │ └──────────────┘ │                                                  
  └──────────────────┘
```

The issue was ultimately related to a file ownership problem, not directly tied to Docker or Visual Studio configurations.
The problem was traced to a permissions issue with the `.docker` directory in the SSH user's home directory. Changing the ownership of the `.docker` directory resolved the issue.